# What is the `.html` used in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I see lots of code snippets that goes:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { something }
  format.json { something }
end
```

I'm wondering what the `html` and `json` are in the above code snippet. Are they methods? Scopes? Attributes?

Comment: Technically, they're methods. Does this answer your question? :)

Comment: it does! but why is that I can't find them in any of the documentations..? I just don't like magic in the box and this to me seems like it..

Comment: `format` is an instance of [`ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/Collector.html), the documentation explains what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's investigate, shall we? This is implementation of [`respond_to`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0e70595acc8796c3e0854ef72df478d597243e68/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L191-L205):

```
def respond_to(*mimes)
  raise ArgumentError, "respond_to takes either types or a block, never both" if mimes.any? && block_given?

  collector = Collector.new(mimes, request.variant)
  yield collector if block_given?

  if format = collector.negotiate_format(request)
    _process_format(format)
    _set_rendered_content_type format
    response = collector.response
    response ? response.call : render({})
  else
    raise ActionController::UnknownFormat
  end
end
```

(the documentation is quite thorough, by the way. Check it out.)

We see that it yields some `Collector` to the block (which you refer to as `format`). Here it is: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0e70595acc8796c3e0854ef72df478d597243e68/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/collector.rb

We see that it just enumerates all Mime content types and generates (dynamically) methods for them. Oh and JFYI, here are all the possible things you can `respond_to`:

```
Mime::SET.map(&:symbol)
=> [:html,
 :text,
 :js,
 :css,
 :ics,
 :csv,
 :vcf,
 :png,
 :jpeg,
 :gif,
 :bmp,
 :tiff,
 :mpeg,
 :xml,
 :rss,
 :atom,
 :yaml,
 :multipart_form,
 :url_encoded_form,
 :json,
 :pdf,
 :zip,
 :doc,
 :excel]
```

Comment: This is the answer I've been struggling for. Thank You !! This is much more sophisticated than I'd imagined but now it finally doesn't seem like some magic. Thank you for the hlep !